# How to display a PostScript file in GTK+?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, gtk, postscript

Does anyone know how to take a PostScript file and display it in a GTK+ application?

I've been trying to use ImageMagick++ to open a PostScript file (which it does just fine), and then somehow open it as an Image in a GtkWidget. I can do this if I have ImageMagick++ save the PostScript file as a PNG image, and then open the PNG image in the GtkWidget, but I'd like to avoid saving a file just because I want to display it.

I've also been playing with using the ImageMagick++ Blob object, but I haven't been able to have GTK+ read the image in the Blob.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The Gnome document viewer [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/?guid=on) has a reusable widget for viewing Postscript files in its libevince library. I don't know where to download it or where the documentation lives, though.

Answer (score 1):

ptomato is in right direction, the easiest way to display a ps/pdf document inside gtk is use libevview and libevdocument (both are part of evince project)

Documentation:

- http://developer.gnome.org/libevview/stable/
- http://developer.gnome.org/libevdocument/stable/